# Use a static nested class with the same generic type as the enclosing class

Tags: java, generics

I have a setup like this:

```
public final class RequestContext<T extends Cache> {
     T roleSpecificCache;

     public static final class Spec implements Supplier<RequestContext> {
          private Spec() {

          }

          T roleSpecificCache; // << Getting error here
     }

     private RequestContext(Spec b) {
        this.roleSpecificCache = b.roleSpecificCache; // << I want to do this
     }
   }
```

However on the line `T roleSpecificCache`, I get the following error
:

```
RequestContext.this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I **understand** the reason why I'm getting this error (i.e. there's no direct link between the two classes), but **don't know how to fix it**. I want to to be  able to do what I'm doing at the end.

Also, I cannot make `Spec` non-static (out of my hands).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to parameterize `Spec`:

```
public final class RequestContext<T extends Cache> {
     T roleSpecificCache;

     public static final class Spec<T extends Cache>
     implements Supplier<RequestContext<T>> {
          private Spec() {
          }

          T roleSpecificCache;
     }

    private RequestContext(Spec<T> b) {
        this.roleSpecificCache = b.roleSpecificCache;
    }
}
```

It kind of seems like it should have been that way to begin with, because of the [raw type argument to `Supplier`, which should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2891664).